# Wpf multiple hyperlinks in one column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In Wpf DataGrid how can we show multiple hyperlinks(Each pointing to different URL) in one column with comma separated.

We have DataGrid with two columns say ID and 'File names'. A single ID can have multiple files.

We need to show it in DataGrid with two columns 'ID' and 'Files' with files associated with id in a single row with file name as comma separated as hyperlink, so user can click on hyperlink and open it.

I could do it for single link but not for multiple hyperlinks. Code for files column to display single column

`<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Files"
 Binding="{Binding FileLink}" ContentBinding="{Binding FileName}" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False">
      <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style>
           <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click"Handler="Hyperlink_Click"/>
       </Style>
       </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, how did it go, can you accept my answer if happy.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own DataGridTemplateColumn with a DataTemplate for each hyperlink, and bind the template to a list of links.

The DataTemplate can be ItemsControl whouse ItemsSource is the list of links

Answer (score 0):

In your list, you could have multiple entries with the same ID but with different files.

What you're trying to achieve must be something like this:

```
ID1 hyperlink1
    hyperlink2
    hyperlink3
ID2 hyperlink1
```

But you could have a list like this:

```
ID1 hyperlink1
ID1 hyperlink2
ID1 hyperlink3
ID2 hyperlink1
```

Comment: Here we are repeating ID column entries. I want something like                 ID1    |   Hyperlink1, hyperlink2 ,hyperlink3

Answer (score 0):

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Actions" IsSmart="True">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock>
                                  <dxe:HyperlinkEdit Name="EditActionLink" AllowAutoNavigate="True" Text="Edit"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock>
                                  <dxe:HyperlinkEdit Name="DeleteActionLink" AllowAutoNavigate="True" Text="Delete"/>
                                </TextBlock>                            
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>                        
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
```